# 400 BAD REQUEST error on attempt to send json to api(Sendgrid) as email information

Tags: json, vb.net, sendgrid

I have a program that has a final step of writing emails to multiple clients. An excel file is made as an attachment to send these emails. I use a api provided by sendgrid to send a email out. However, I get an exception when the getresponse stage is triggered: "400 bad request." I tried checking the validity of the api key and the url using postman. It was successful there so I think it is possible my json conversion/syntax is incorrect. I am unsure, I just started using visual basic about a month ago.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

            Dim attachmentpath As String = strAppPath & strFileCompleteDir
            Dim uri As String = "URL"
            Dim Request As WebRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri)
            Request.Method = "POST"
            Request.PreAuthenticate = True
            Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer 'API_KEY'")
         

            Dim json_data As String = "{'personalizations': [{'To': [{'email': ''To_email''}]}],'from': {'email': 'From_email'},'subject': '[encrypt]Hello, World! test','content': [{'type': 'text/plain', 'value': 'Heya!'}]}"

            Request.ContentType = "application/json"
            Dim json_bytes() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json_data)
            Request.ContentLength = json_bytes.Length


            Using requeststream = Request.GetRequestStream
                requeststream.Write(json_bytes, 0, json_bytes.Length)
            End Using

            Dim responsecontent As String = Nothing
            Using Response = DirectCast(Request.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse),
                    responseStream = Response.GetResponseStream()
                Using reader = New StreamReader(responseStream)
                    responsecontent = reader.ReadToEnd()
                End Using
            End Using
```

Comment: A JSON should enclose strings in double quotes: `'personalizations'` -> `"personalizations"` etc. The API may be *sensible* to this. You should probably build a class object that describes the WebRequest parameters and serialize it. I don't see how you're actually setting the token, but don't enclose it in single quotes inside the `bearer` string. You're probably better off using HttpClient. See the [AuthenticationHeaderValue(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue.-ctor) example.

Comment: So create can I create a local object in this method? and use New JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize(object) in order to maintain "" instead of '', and no the apikey when implemented is without ''.

Comment: *create a local object*: a class object. Build a class structure (a model) that describes the JSON. So you can also verify whether the `personalizations` object actually has to be an array. -- The JSON is simple, JavascriptSerializer is ok, if you don't have `Json.Net` installed or you cannot use `System.Text.Json`

Comment: Is there example code on this. and right now i have a Newtonsoft.Json import. Im unsure its an array here is the exact copy and pasted json code from postman that worked. {"personalizations":
 [{"to": [{"email": "myemial"}]}],"from": {"email": "aemail"},"subject": "[encrypt]Hello, World! test","content": [{"type": "text/plain", "value": "Heya!"}]}

Comment: First thing, just test whether the JSON format is causing the error. In VB.Net, just double the double-quotes, as in `dim json = "{""personalizations"": [{""to"": [{""email"": ""myemail""}]}],""from"": {""email"": ""aemail""},""subject"": ""[encrypt]Hello, World! test"",""content"": [{""type"": ""text/plain"", ""value"": ""Heya!""}]}"`. If this is accepted, then you can build your class structure (model, as you want to call it), so it's simpler to reuse and harder to introduce typing errors. Don't use Visual Studio's `Paste JSON as Classes`, it'll get it wrong.

Comment: Okay thats awesome it worked. okay question is it possible to just use that string and make the to email and attachment dynamic?